# Qlik Sense - One line graph, with two lines that need a different scale (one with values of 1000, the other with values of 10)

Tags: graph, qlikview

I have a one line graph, with two lines that need a different scale, each on the Y axis (one with values of 1000, the other with values of 10)
I have 5 machines, so 5 results for each function.
    Measure 1: Avg(Speed): 1000, 800, 1000, 700, 600
    Measure 2: Count(PartsProduced): 3, 5, 23, 50, 10
When I create the graph - you can't really see the results of Measure 2. I want to create a second Y axis because I need to see them combined.

Thanks!

Comment: Please add some data so we can understand the request better

Comment: Sorry! I'm having trouble with formatting the text nicely. Hope this helps, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After you've created both of your measures (Qlik calls them expressions), navigate to the 'Axes' tab in your chart properties dialog and select one of your expressions from the list. Once you've made your selection, choose the 'Right (Top)' radio button in the 'Position' section. See image below:

[image]

Comment: I am sorry I am using Qlik Sense now... I know how to move a legend from side to side, problem is I need two different valued Y axis for one graph... Thanks!

Comment: I see. To be clear, my answer would accomplish what you need in Qlikview as the Position section of the Axes tab controls which Y-axis an expression is set to, not the legend. Unfortunately, I do not have any experience with Qlik Sense so I'm afraid I cannot offer an answer. I did however find [this on the Qlik community](https://community.qlik.com/thread/135276).

Comment: You're the best! Just so you know... before writing anything here I really bang my head against the wall trying almost every function. Thanks!